# Select value from one table based one matching value and one value that may or may not match

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I am trying to get a value from a row in one table that matches one value and matches or selects next closet lower value. See table examples and I have provided a way to do it one row at a time.

### Table Vendor Cost

| Part | Quantity | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BLK CAT | 20 | 5 |
| BLK CAT | 50 | 4 |
| BLK CAT | 100 | 3 |
| BLK CAT | 250 | 2 |
| BLK CAT | 500 | 1 |
| WHT CAT | 5 | 68 |
| WHT CAT | 25 | 50 |
| WHT CAT | 60 | 25 |

### Table Price Breaks before update

| Part | Quantity | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BLK CAT | 25 |  |
| BLK CAT | 50 |  |
| BLK CAT | 80 |  |
| BLK CAT | 100 |  |
| BLK CAT | 200 |  |
| WHT CAT | 10 |  |
| WHT CAT | 25 |  |
| WHT CAT | 50 |  |

### Table Price Breaks after update

| Part | Quantity | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| BLK CAT | 25 | 5 |
| BLK CAT | 50 | 4 |
| BLK CAT | 80 | 4 |
| BLK CAT | 100 | 3 |
| BLK CAT | 200 | 3 |
| WHT CAT | 10 | 68 |
| WHT CAT | 25 | 50 |
| WHT CAT | 50 | 50 |

### My update statement so far

```
Update #StandardPList Set UnitCost = VC.Cost
From #StandardPList
  Inner Join 
      (
        Select PartNum, Cost
        From #VendorCost
        Where PartNum = @PartNum
        And BreakQty = (
                Select Top 1 Max(BreakQty) As NextLowBrk 
                From #VendorCost
                Where PartNum = @PartNum And BreakQty < @Qty
                )
      ) VC On #StandardPList.PartNum = VC.PartNum And #StandardPList.Quantity = @Qty
```

Comment: Please provide data and expected results as text in your question, [not as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question), we can't copy and paste data from an image.

Comment: What is your DBMS? Without knowing it, it is hard to give a correct answer. Then, table and column names of your image and query don't match. Please correct this.

Comment: SQL Sever: Windows Server 2019 Standard (10.0)

Comment: Vendor Cost:      
Part Quantity Cost  
BLK CAT 20  5   
BLK CAT 50  4   
BLK CAT 100  3   
BLK CAT 250  2   
BLK CAT 500  1   
WHT CAT 5  68   
WHT CAT 25  50   
WHT CAT 60  25  

Price Breaks:
Part Quantity Cost 
BLK CAT 25
BLK CAT 50
BLK CAT 80
BLK CAT 100
BLK CAT 200     
WHT CAT 10
WHT CAT 25
WHT CAT 50

Result    
Price Breaks:     
Part Quantity Cost   
BLK CAT 25  5   
BLK CAT 50  4   
BLK CAT 80  4   
BLK CAT 100  3   
BLK CAT 200  3   
WHT CAT 10  68   
WHT CAT 25  50   
WHT CAT 50  50

Comment: You can edit your request by clicking the `edit` link below it. I've done that for you now. I've replaced the image with formatted text (I used https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ for this), added the SQL Server tags and removed the stored procedure tag, because here is no stored procedure involved; you want a mere SQL update statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a join. Just update the price break table and use a correlated subquery to get the cost for the maximum quantity that is less or equal the price break quantity.

```
update #standardplist
set unitcost = 
(
  select top(1) vc.cost
  from #vendorcost vc
  where vc.partnum = #standardplist.partnum
  and vc.breakqty <= #standardplist.quantity
  order by vc.breakqty desc
);
```

Usually, this is something you shouldn't do though. The cost is already available in your database and can be queried whenever needed. By storing it again in the price list table you introduce redundancy. This is something we avoid in databases, because redundancy can easily lead to inconsistencies.

If, however, the vendore cost table is subject to change, but the standard price list costs are to remain fixed, then this will no longer be redundancy, as the stored cost can be different from the current vendor costs. I will have no objections then.

Comment: Yes both tables involved change often. The answer does not work because the select statement cannot bind to the spl reference

Comment: Obviously, SQL Server does not support the table alias here. Weird. I've updated my answer.

Comment: that change resolved the issue.